# Could someone explain to me in simple terms how to install this specific Java platform?

Tags: installation, java, minecraft

I am in no way adept with Ubuntu.  I've installed it on my Samsung Chromebook in order to play Minecraft, but every version of Flash I've tried will not work.  I figured it was because I needed this specific version installed found [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html)

It's the first one called Linux ARM v6/v7 Hard Float ABI.  It's a .tar.gz, which I have extracted, but don't know where to go from there.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing OpenJDK and IcedTea Plugin from Software Center. It's easier to do if you have no experience. https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/openjdk-7-jre

Comment: Unfortunately, none of the software center versions of Java work.  Everytime I try to open Minecraft utilizing OpenJDK or other flash versions it will open the launcher but when I try to click play, the whole thing closes.

Comment: As I know, Minecraft don't use flash at all. There can be other reasons why Minecraft crashes. You should look for crash raports in /home/%username%/.minecraft folder.

Answer (score 0):

its not a flat extraction. It has to hook into the system.

Move the tar.gz file where you want to extract. Then `tar zxvf <file-name>.tar.gz`

[source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/linux/linux-jre.html)

Or just install open JDK from the software center